# Is there an API for accessing my Windows Live calendar data?

Tags: .net, calendar

Google calendar has an API. Does Windows Live provide something similar?
Here is a link to the Google API:
http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html
I am looking for an equivalent from Microsoft.

Comment: I think their API is called "Export". GCal has another API feature called "Import" I think. I bet you could get the two to work together somehow, and maybe use the rest of Google's API.

Comment: Export and Import are fine but I want to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx#wleventscreate the ability to create events on a Windows Live calendar.  I haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I found is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#event

But I haven't done anything with it so far, will try out soon...

Answer (score 0):

The main API page for Hotmail/Windows Live calendars and contacts appears to be at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/hh528486.

I also found a page at http://preview.library.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/gg241159 with instructions for creating event links for the Hotmail calendar. I don't know why it's at that odd URL, but the instructions seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile and Windows desktop apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826529.aspx

Windows Store apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826551.aspx

Windows Phone apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826550.aspx

The one you need is the first and you will see an complete example of API usage. It uses a browser control to sign in.

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264574.aspx lists Microsoft's Live APIs. A cursory scan suggests that calender data access is not available.

Another resource on programmatic access to Live data: http://dev.live.com/

Sorry that I don't have better news for you. :-(

Comment: You might be right. On the other hand, it's difficult to imagine that Microsoft would be so stupid as to not provide access to their calendar.

Comment: You would think it would be among the first APIs on offer but then Microsft do provide Office Live services so maybe they are afraid of providing a key component to an online competitor to Outlook.

Comment: Calendar access is now available http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx